# Azure Devops AzureCLI@2 az bicep build Can't Find bicepConfig.json

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-bicep

I'm running a Azure Devops `AzureCLI@2` step that compiles my `main.bicep` file before I put it in an artifact to deploy that infrastructure later.

I'm getting an error that the defined modules in my `bicepConfig.json` file are not being found.

Here is my pipeline YAML

```yaml
  - job: publish_bicep
    displayName: Publish Bicep Template
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      name: validate_bicep
      displayName: Validate Bicep
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscriptionsId }}
        scriptType: pscore
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        powerShellErrorActionPreference: stop
        failOnStandardError: false
        inlineScript: |
          ls $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/environment
          az bicep build --file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/environment/main.bicep

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Copying Bicep Templates
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        Contents: |
          environment/*.bicep
          environment/*.json
        TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifact: bicepTemplates
```

And here are the errors I'm getting

```
/usr/bin/az account set --subscription REMOVED
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1703777321399.ps1'
bicepConfig.json
main.bicep
bicep.cert.parameters.json
bicep.prod.parameters.json
bicep.test.parameters.json
ERROR: /home/vsts/work/1/s/environment/main.bicep(20,17) : Error BCP212: The Template Spec module alias name "myrepo" does not exist in the built-in Bicep configuration.
/home/vsts/work/1/s/environment/main.bicep(48,28) : Error BCP212: The Template Spec module alias name "wegmans" does not exist in the built-in Bicep configuration.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by changing `ubuntu-latest` to `windows-latest`.

I suspect it might have something to do with the weird casing I used when naming the file (bicepConfig.json instead of bicepconfig.json) that Ubuntu can't handle, and Azure DevOps won't let me change it now that the camel casing is checked in.

Either way, changing the `vmImage` fixed this for me.

Comment: you can change the case => rename the file from azure devops website

Answer (score 0):

I have just copy and paste your code and test at my side, remain the vmImage "ubuntu-latest", it works well.

```
jobs:
  - job: publish_bicep
    displayName: Publish Bicep Template
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      name: validate_bicep
      displayName: Validate Bicep
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscriptionsId }}
        scriptType: pscore
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        powerShellErrorActionPreference: stop
        failOnStandardError: false
        inlineScript: |
          ls $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/environment
          az bicep build --file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/environment/main.bicep

    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Copying Bicep Templates
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
        Contents: |
          environment/*.bicep
          environment/*.json
        TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

    - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      artifact: bicepTemplates
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your answer doesn't contain anything about the bicepconfig.json which was the issue I was having.